# How to open apps downloaded from app store in xcode(ssh)?

Tags: xcode, ssh, ipod

I ssh'd into my iPod and transferred an app's folder (with the .app file) to my desktop. Is there anyway I can open this in XCode and view the source code? If you want to know more information just ask.

Answer (score 2):

No, the source code no longer exists in a compiled `.app`.